# sed: Replace FIRST occurence of space with newline

Tags: regex, linux, file, sed

I am trying to replace the *first* occurrence of a space in each line with a newline.

For instance

```
123 there is a monkey
567 there is also a tiger
```

would become

```
123
there is a monkey
567
there is also a tiger
```

I have tried doing this with the command:

```
sed -e 's/^\s\+/\n/g' output.txt > new.txt
```

with no luck. I am also open to any other programs in linux that would allow me to do this such as awk, perl, or bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed $'s/ \{1,\}/\\\n/' file
123
there is a monkey
567
there is also a tiger
```

This works both on BSD as well on gnu sed.

Comment: Doesn't `$'foo'` require bash, though?

Comment: Yes that is BASH syntax.

Comment: The `$'`...`'` syntax also works in ksh 93+, both AT&T and pd.

Comment: This replaced every space with newline for me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't anchor the regex at the beginning of the line and ditch the `g` flag:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/' output.txt > new.txt
```

EDIT: BSD sed part removed because of pain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
awk '{sub(FS,RS)}1' file
123
there is a monkey
567
there is also a tiger
```

It changes the first field separator with record selector.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers that work in GNU sed but not BSD sed (such as you'll find on a Mac).  BSD sed, for example, won't turn `\n` into a literal newline. Assuming you're in bash or modern ksh, you can use ANSI strings `$'...'` to get around that problem.  All of the answers below work in either version.

First, if you know for sure it's just one space, you can do this:

```
sed $'s/ /\\\n/'
```

If you want to handle the case where there may be more than one space in a row, you can do this:

```
sed $'s/  */\\\n/'   # that's space, space, asterisk
```

Or you can use extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E $'s/ +/\\\n/'
```

If you want to handle arbitrary whitespace (e.g. tabs as well as spaces), then you can replace the literal space characters above with `[[:space:]]`.

Alternately, you can use Perl, which has no version incompatibilities:

```
perl -pe 's/\s+/\n/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
sed -e 's/\s/\n/' output.txt > new.txt
```

should suffice. If you drop the global flag it will match the first char and sed works by line.